# Typescript - Cannot update object within an object

Tags: typescript, object

I have a Typescript object as follows:

```
export class DocumentIndex {
  objectId: number;
  key = '';
  iconPath = '';
  searchParm: SearchParm = new SearchParm();

  constructor(public name: string, public description: string) {
    this.objectId = JsUtil.getObjectId();
  }
}
```

My goal is to change the values of the SearchParm object. The SearchParm object is defined as follows:

```
export class SearchParm {
  searchType = SearchType.none;
  searchTerm = '';
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Here is the code where I attempt to set the searchTerm and the searchType to another value:

```
let docIndex = new DocumentIndex(searchValue, '');

docIndex.searchParm.searchTerm = searchValue; // searchValue is a string set to "G Triad"
docIndex.searchParm.searchType = SearchType.fullText; // this is a string set to "fullText"

console.log('documentIndex searchParm...', docIndex.searchParm);
console.log('documentIndex...', docIndex);
```

Here is the result in Chrome. Note that the SearchParm remains unchanged from what it was originally set to.

[image: Chrome result]

What could be happening here? The same code was used elsewhere in what I'm working on and works correctly.

Comment: I've since solved the issue. It indeed was being modified outside of what I showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `console.log(obj)` for some object `obj`, you might think that it will log to the console something information about the state of `obj` when you logged it.  This is not guaranteed to be true.  It's often the case that browsers will keep a reference to `obj` and whenever you look at the console you will see the *current* state of `obj`.  So if you modify `obj` after you log it, you might be confused:

```
const obj = {foo: "bar"}; // empty
console.log(obj); // what gets logged here?  {foo: "bar"} or {foo: "baz"}?
obj.foo = "baz";
```

For that code, Firefox shows me the following collapsed/expanded view:

```
// collapsed view
// ▶ Object { foo: "bar" }

// expanded view
// ▼ {…}
//   foo: "baz"
```

So you can't really rely on what `console.log()` does with object references.  Instead, you might consider [doing something like `JSON.stringify(obj)` before logging it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects).  That would have the advantage of capturing at least some of the state of the logged object at the time of the logging:

```
const obj = {foo: "bar"}; // empty
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // definitely logs {"foo":"bar"}
obj.foo = "baz";
```

---

In your case, I strongly suspect that you are reassigning `docIndex.searchParm` after your logging code.  That could easily cause `console.log(docIndex)` to show the current value of its `searchParm` property, while `console.log(docIndex.searchParm)` to show the current value of the object that *used to be* its `searchParm` property:

```
docIndex.searchParm.searchTerm = searchValue; // searchValue is a string set to "G Triad"
docIndex.searchParm.searchType = SearchType.fullText; // this is a string set to "fullText"

console.log('documentIndex searchParm...', docIndex.searchParm);
console.log('documentIndex...', docIndex);

// this happens later 
docIndex.searchParm = new SearchParm();

// documentIndex searchParm... Object { searchType: "fullText", searchTerm: "G Triad" }
// documentIndex... searchParm:  ▼ {…} 
//                                   Object { searchType: "none", searchTerm: "" }
```

The problem should disappear if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify())`:

```
console.log('documentIndex searchParm...', JSON.stringify(docIndex.searchParm));
// documentIndex searchParm... documentIndex searchParm... {"searchType":"fullText","searchTerm":"G Triad"}

console.log('documentIndex...', JSON.stringify(docIndex));
// documentIndex... searchParm:  {"name":"G Triad","description":"","key":"",
//  "iconPath": "", "searchParm": { "searchType": "fullText", "searchTerm": "G Triad" }, 
//  "objectId": 123}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGAzEIBcMARPAIYBOhMAvgNwwD09MApgLYAOUAngLABQoSCAA2zAHTCQAcwAUCRAEo6jGAHcAFiVhTmUCDElSdAExjrmZZgH4YGHPiKkKVOGTu4CxEgC9CVK-zyYvaojj6ENPz8KoBtpDAA8kjMwLCY9p5OlFRRfCqAPaQYgGQE2blMtulhvjlgJKzMEOwkwMwwAMo17BDqIKn8toLQcEihaR5hFNTKTGycvHz94BAi4oYyAFKt8QByYtBkAJZgUvtYXHJICkoMTMbMWIf7UMzCXAbS+uiE9oR4Xs59Q0QwVwoS8vkifBK-GAwhIEH0ABEQMAAK51MBQACSYFuAA8MAD5MkscYCGA0fALBDbABrZivNAAckZ1Jg+0EAAUtOpQszWRBmORgOouWRWARWoKyMLRaxQmBmKo2lKZeRWDIlDkFpAoGQUSkQGQZOwUfBhOyYDU6gQ9ocpAAaGAms0W24QYAHTj7cA23V2hQE+a2GBQdT7CBiIkpTGmNAARgATABmVklKECWHw5VCkVqwO2AU5gAqXHYLTQkuLpfEYHAzH5KvURYscqZLIBA11+qgho1+eo-HTnZghel6gAaiRhCjy0QAOIwIsHEjGCL8ZjkuWVsclsv92sK0EH5iEe0ArAo4TCZu42BoL6X6-MW+EQc5USwYzI7F4+WKmBIqi6JYjiz4yKOwqTtOzCOsymp8PwX7AD+z67I2spocWLahBBE5TjOUwjo2UEzmy+gkCOfpHERsA9vOi7LquiHfqBuKYWOGG4bus7bsK3HBI+N5QIRobhmRMAUba1ECrRIBEBeV5Ca+CECIsywSNIMiMkhaIbiBv64RhYhiIyjpIShbGGWq8EqDpwEWUROZGWICRJCkGCOTu1aeApT4vo6XEtp4C5LvsK5ZDkAzqas2nIrpGIWcZJlmSxeI2TccX2axSWeaqYoEDABToMUMDRGUwYVZVVXVTViSIMSHlcd5RDHqeuVNkFRARSpUWiBpsixUBekOVZYpJaZMAbNsuxUccpwyOZ2WjawlwQrZmXDax7XOTAdmbQZ6FqjlnxNWWPwPopz5QKehCBWK50hYxfiRWpfUxXtCXZcZE1TTsUlzWci1pelu0bZ9eI5ctBWfFaJ6-I9YWrvahBuh6+xeuA503XSXBY2epS2IQ7LgFyoY-F1jq3Yd90EJgVNVmdPmCVdbX0zuLbk4QCPhdQjplYTUYkuTiZJum-OifomjsGWkAGFoFilXwQOoctf5KrxuZihqEJ9EAA)